# Load data form Azure/IEnumerable to ListBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, azure, mvvm

Basic question, I want to load data from Azure server and see send it to XAML. Could be ListBox or LongListSelector (best option). Could you correct my code? What am I doing wrong?

Loading data from Azure and send it to IEnumerable collection.

ViewModel

```
             public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
                {
                    private readonly ICommand _loadDataCommand;
                    private MobileServiceCollection<ModelAzure, ModelAzure> _items;
                    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
                    public IEnumerable itemsControl;

              private async void RefreshTodoItems()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _items = await _todoTable.ToCollectionAsync();
                    }
                    catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error loading items, please try again :)", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                    }
                   itemsControl = _items;
                }



                public ICommand LoadDataCommand
                {
                    get { return this._loadDataCommand; }
                }

                private void LoadDataAction(object p)
                {
                    RefreshTodoItems();
                }

                public IEnumerable AzureData
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return itemsControl;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        itemsControl = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged("AzureData");
                    }
                }

         private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
}
```

XAML

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding AzureData}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Text" Height="180"
                 />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the AzureData using the setter.. not just the private backing variable so that the RaisePropertyChanged event gets triggered.

```
AzureData = _items;
```